# How to get a PhoneStateListener when using Dual SIM functionality

Tags: android, mobile, kotlin, dual-sim

so I am currently implementing a call forwarding feature in Android, for dual SIM devices. In order to read the current state of the call forwarding (enabled/disabled) for a SIM card, I do the following:

1. I create a `TelephonyManager` object:

`val telephonyManager = getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager`

2. I create a `PhoneStateListener` object and override the `onCallForwardingIndicatorChanged` method:

   ```
   val myPhoneStateListener = object: PhoneStateListener() {
     override fun onCallForwardingIndicatorChanged(isCallForwardingEnabled: Boolean) {
       if(isCallForwardingEnabled) println("Call forwarding enabled!")
       else println("Call forwarding disabled!")
     }
   }
   ```
3. I registered the `PhoneStateListener`:

`telephonyManager.listen(myPhoneStateListener, LISTEN_CALL_FORWARDING_INDICATOR)`

This works perfectly fine for the primary (the first) SIM card.

But I am having trouble doing the same for the second SIM card. Here is how I am trying to do it:

1. I use a `SubscriptionManager` object to retrieve the subscriptionId of the second SIM card:

   ```
   val subscriptionManager = getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE) as SubscriptionManager
   val subscriptionIdOfSimCard2 = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoForSimSlotIndex(1).subscriptionId
   ```
2. I create a separate `TelephonyManager` for the second SIM card, with the correct subscriptionId:

   ```
   val secondTelephonyManager = (getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager).createForSubscriptionId(subscriptionIdOfSimCard2)
   ```
3. I create a second `PhoneStateListener`, just like the one for the first SIM card, lets call it `mySecondPhoneStateListener` and register it with the second `TelephonyManager`:

   ```
   secondTelephonyManager.listen(mySecondPhoneStateListener, LISTEN_CALL_FORWARDING_INDICATOR)
   ```

The problem now is, that in mySecondPhoneStateListener I don't get callbacks for the second SIM card, but still the primary, first one. After digging around in the Android source code, I found out why that is: In the `listen(PhoneStateListener listener, int events)` method of the `TelephonyManager` the wrong subscriptionId is used, i.e. not the one set in the `TelephonyManager` but the one in the `PhoneStateListener` object, which is the subscriptionId of the first SIM card, by default:

```
public void listen(PhoneStateListener listener, int events) {
    if (mContext == null) return;
    try {
        Boolean notifyNow = (getITelephony() != null);
        sRegistry.listenForSubscriber(listener.mSubId, */ HERE: listener.mSubId is used instead of this.mSubId */
            getOpPackageName(), listener.callback, events, notifyNow);
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        // system process dead
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        // system process dead
    }
}
```

This problem could be solved by setting the correct subscriptionId for the `PhoneStateListener` object, however the appropriate constructor is hidden:

```
/**
 * Create a PhoneStateListener for the Phone using the specified subscription.
 * This class requires Looper.myLooper() not return null. To supply your
 * own non-null Looper use PhoneStateListener(int subId, Looper looper) below.
 * @hide */<-- HIDDEN, NOT ACCESSIBLE*/
 */
public PhoneStateListener(int subId) {
    this(subId, Looper.myLooper());
}
```

I was able to "solve" this with reflection, by setting the mSubId field of the `PhoneStateListener` object to the appropriate subscriptionId of the second SIM card.

But there has to be a better way to do this, am I missing something?

Comment: Did you actually use reflection to call the mentioned constructor or did you use reflection to overwrite the mSubId field ?

Comment: @TiGer I used reflection to override the mSubId field. I couldn't figure out how to use the constructor with reflection and at the same time override the onCallForwardingIndocatorChanged method.

Answer (score 0):

I make simple ArrayList with Listeners and it's work for me fine (it's Kotlin btw)

In my activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.sim_selector)
    checkForForwarding()
}

fun getSimsCount(): Int {
    val subscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(this)
    val activeSubscriptionInfoList = subscriptionManager.activeSubscriptionInfoList
    return activeSubscriptionInfoList.size
}

class SimForwardListeners{
    var subscriptionId: Int = 0
    lateinit var manager: TelephonyManager
    lateinit var phoneStateListener: MyPhoneStateListener
}

private val simsForwardListeners: ArrayList<SimForwardListeners> = arrayListOf()

fun checkForForwarding() {
    val subscriptionManager = getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE) as SubscriptionManager

    for (slotIndex in 0 until getSimsCount()) {
        val z = SimForwardListeners()
        z.phoneStateListener = MyPhoneStateListener(slotIndex)
        z.phoneStateListener.setView(this)
        z.subscriptionId = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoForSimSlotIndex(slotIndex).subscriptionId
        z.manager = (getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager).createForSubscriptionId(z.subscriptionId)
        z.manager.listen(z.phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_FORWARDING_INDICATOR)
        simsForwardListeners.add(z)
    }
}
```