# Using multiple TelephonyManagers with multi-sim device

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am trying to establish whenever a multisim Android device (running Android 7.0+) has any working/enabled sim cards.
For this I am following Google's documentation regarding attaching multiple TelephonyManagers to the  default TelephonyManager instance, as per : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#SIM_STATE_READY

> The returned TelephonyManager will use the default subscription for
>   all calls. To call an API for a specific subscription, use
>   createForSubscriptionId(int). e.g. telephonyManager =
>   defaultSubTelephonyManager.createForSubscriptionId(subId);

In my specific case something like this :

```
 telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) mContext
                   .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE);


List subList = mSubManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
        SubscriptionInfo firstSub = (SubscriptionInfo) subList.get(0);
    mSim0TelephonyManager = telephonyManager.createForSubscriptionId(firstSub.getSubscriptionId());
    mSim0TelephonyManager.listen(new Sim0PhoneStateListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE);
    int test = mSim0TelephonyManager.getSimState();

SubscriptionInfo secondSub = (SubscriptionInfo) subList.get(1);
 mSim1TelephonyManager = telephonyManager.createForSubscriptionId(secondSub.getSubscriptionId());
mSim1TelephonyManager.listen(new Sim1PhoneStateListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE);
 int testw = mSim1TelephonyManager.getSimState();
```

So first I get all active subscriptions ,which was already a pain because in reality those are not active subscriptions as in subscriptions who have state in service, those are simply the SIM cards inserted into the SIM slots.

Which means that even if you deactivate a SIM card using the Android Settings Menu you will still receive that SIM card as being an active subscription !!!!

The next problem is that even on deactivated (No service!!!) SIM cards I am getting a value 5 (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#SIM_STATE_READY). For me this is incomprehensible, the SIM state is ready whilst the whole SIM is deactivated. This means those API calls are not reliable at all...

Also after adding the PhoneStateListeners to the individual new TelephonyManagers I am not getting any calls to the implementations of those PhoneStateListeners when the SIM cards are activates/deactivated through the Android Settings Menu...

Now I am wondering if something is broke within Android, or maybe with the device manufacturers implementations (testing on a Samsung A5 2017 Duo and a Huawei P9 Lite). Unfortunately the emulator does not support multi-sim so I cannot test the plain vanilla Android Nougat version on that :(

**UPDATE :**

In the meantime I found this topic : [How to get a PhoneStateListener when using Dual SIM functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352840/how-to-get-a-phonestatelistener-when-using-dual-sim-functionality)

It would seem there is actually a bug within Google's implementation within listen(PhoneStateListener listener, int events) which results in a PhoneStateListener being instantiated only for the default SubscriptionId independently from the parameter which is being passed in the constructor....

Comment: If you are getting the same results across multiple disparate manufacturers (Samsung and Huawei), then most likely the problem is with Android. It's possible the problem would be with the chipset manufacturer, if those devices happen to share a common chipset manufacturer. Unfortunately, there is no multi-SIM Google device (Nexus or Pixel) to use as a reference point.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try but it might work for you

```
subids[] = SubscriptionManager.getSubscriptionId()
if (SubscriptionManager.isActiveSubscriptionId(subids[0])){
    mSim0TelephonyManager = telephonyManager.createForSubscriptionId(firstSub.getSubscriptionId());
}
```

this will work